# Autocomplete text

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey, autocomplete, productivity

Here's a doubt, there is a tool that has the autocomplete function (such as https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60998-autocomplete-12/) with the addition that if I start to write another word and I return to a previous word, it recognizes the whole word for me if I start adding letters to it.
In this gif I explain it better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9fJ.jpg

What I would like is for it to recognize the already typed word when I place the cursor on it and continue giving me text suggestions, as in Visual Studio Code or another IDE but in any text box.
I appreciate in advance any recommendation since I have spent a lot of time looking for something like this and the only thing I found that meets this condition is the test.ahk file of this project on GitHub, but it only works in a specific Gui. The project: https://github.com/A-AhkUser/eAutocomplete

The gif of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the windows 10/11 inbuilt tool? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-text-suggestions-in-windows-0bf313ca-c992-4173-aa5f-8341d3953498#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes, what happens is that I would like there to be a number next to the suggestion to select it directly and more suggestions. If there was a way to do this, it would be the best option!